# Tool to collect and read all linux logs in one place

Tags: linux, logging, log-files, automation

I have two linux servers. I'm an administrator, and part of my daily routine is to check all the logs for errors or strange messages. So, every morning I check:

On server #1:

```
/var/log/syslog
/var/www/example.com/error.log
/var/log/redis.log
...and so on
```

On server #2:

```
/var/log/syslog
/var/lib/mysql_error.log
/var/lib/mysql_slow.log
```

Opening each file through terminal is very boring and unproductive. Is there some tool, that can collect logs from all servers and display them in one place?

Comment: [splunk?](http://www.splunk.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution thats really popular these days is [Logstash](http://logstash.net/).

Open source, and scalable.

Comment: This. And make sure to use [Kibana](http://kibana.org/) as the web frontend instead of the one included with Logstash. (Kibana is likely to become the official frontend in the not-too-distant future.)

Answer (score 2):

There is the quite simple [`logcheck`](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/logcheck.xml) that sends you emails and allows filtering good stuff by own regex rules.

[OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/doc/manual/monitoring/index.html) has also an quite good log monitoring tool.

[LogAnalyzer](http://loganalyzer-demo.adiscon.com/) looks like a nice gui and appears to be connected somehow to `rsyslog`.

Edit: [Logstash](https://serverfault.com/a/477439/100094) looks really great. Did not knew about it.

There are probably other tools such as [scribe](https://github.com/facebook/scribe) from facebook or [log.io](http://logio.org/) for more sophisticated and different purposes.

I think just spend some minutes googling for log monitoring should give you a rather long list of solutions.

But it's hard to decide what fits your needs and what not. It's also not always very straightforward to come up with a configuration that not spams you with unimportant stuff and is also reliable if something goes wrong. I found `logcheck` to be too verbose by default and OSSEC quite nice.